# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions

[How to achieve highly accurate car physics such as Liveforspeed?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37950/how-to-achieve-highly-accurate-car-physics-such-as-liveforspeed/37951#37951)

I read this question and thought it is definitely about:

> 1. "How do I get started"
> 2. what language/engine/SDK you should learn next
> 3. which technology to use
> 4. what technology some particular game used
> 5. how to make (or start making) a particular type of game

And this question could require a series of books to answer.

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Should we close this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think it should be closed, flag it ("It doesn't belong here" is the flag option you want, followed by the reasoning).  For those with enough points to cast close votes directly, just do that.

There's usually no need to ask for consensus on closing a particular question in meta, except when there's a question about (or disagreement with) broader policy, as in [your other question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/what-is-a-good-question-about-game-industry-careers).

Comment: The reason I'm asking is not in order to close the question, I am wondering about what people think in order to know how the faq reflects in practice.

Comment: Watch the question and see what happens over the next day or two, I guess?  I don't really see the point of this question.